# Prove the integral formula using complex parametrization

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove $\displaystyle{\int_{\large{c}}\frac{\cos(e^z)}{z^2}dz=-2\pi i \sin(1)}$ using parametrization $c(t)=e^{it}, t \in (0, 2\pi]$.

Substituting in the parametrization, I obtain $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\cos{e^{\large{e^{it}}}}}{e^{2it}} \cdot ie^{it}dt=i\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos{e^{\large{e^{it}}}}}{e^{it}}$$

However, I am unable to proceed forward with this integral. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed use well-known theorems like Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @MartinR. I think that it is

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: You are right. I had computed the second derivative.

Comment: @MartinR Yes I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the given parametrization misled you to using a substitution method, when it was there only to explicit the contour of integration.

This kind of integral can be handled with the help of residues, as follows :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_\mathcal{C} \frac{\cos(e^z)}{z^2} \mathrm{d}z
   &=& \displaystyle 
   \sum_{k\ge0} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} \int_\mathcal{C} \frac{e^{2kz}}{z^2} \mathrm{d}z \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   2\pi i\sum_{k\ge0} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} \,\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2kz}}{z^2},z=0\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   2\pi i\sum_{k\ge0} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} \,2k \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   2\pi i\sum_{k\ge1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)!} \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   2\pi i\sum_{k\ge0} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\
   &=& \displaystyle 
   -2\pi i\sin(1)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe tell me why we're allowed to swap the integral and the sum in the first step?

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker   As a physicist, I must admit that my justification is "It was a valid move because it produces a solution" x) More seriously, I don't remember exactly, but you should look at Fubini's theorem or dominated convergence.